# Cube root of a line

Tags: geometric-construction

Well this may be simple but I am not getting it.

> Give a line segment (of length $l$)(and a segment of unit length if you require) how to construct a line of length $l^{1/3}$ with only a straight edge and compass?

I know how to draw a line with length $\sqrt l$ (through similarity process) but am at a loss at the cube root one. Can someone help?

Comment: in general, cubic root is not constructible by compass and straightedge alone. That's how people finally figure out classical geometry problem like doubling the cube or trisecting an angle is unsolvable.

Comment: @achillehui Is there any proof or so? Just asking.. (But  cubing a line is possible I know so I thought...)

Comment: Look at wiki page of [constructible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number)  and refs there as a start.

Comment: Or the the part showing $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible in [doubling the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube#Proof_of_impossibility)

Comment: @Henry So you say $2^{1/5}$ is also not constructible?

Comment: Indeed it is not

Comment: @Qwerty : however you [can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube#Using_a_marked_ruler) construct $2^{1/3}$ by a _de neusis_ construction, using a marked ruler.

Comment: @Henry  and Watson : So I see that a  given line segment of unit length is not the same as a marked ruler. Have I got this correct?

Comment: Given a marked ruler, you can freely move the ruler against your graph until a certain condition is met. In this process, you solved a cubic equation. However, you can't achieve "continuous motion" with a line segment and unmarked ruler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of rational root theorem, it's not possible to draw cubed root of 2. However, I have found folks who figured things out using Euclidean geometry.

This one is the simplest:
https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConstructingTheCubeRootOfTwo/#more

Also, I came up with a hack myself. My approach is clunky and not precise past the thousandths decimal. I made this hack based upon some simple facts that

- cubed root of 2 is 1.25992105...
- sin(39.045) = 0.629930566
- 2x(sin(39.045)) = 1.25986113

So if you had an isosceles triangle with the apex 78.09 degrees and the two sides are length 1, then the base should be 1.259.

Step 1: Create an angle that is .46875 degrees
Construct a right angle.
Trisect the right angle.
Take one of the 30 degree angles and bisect it 6 times. You will get an angle that is .46875 degrees.

Step 2: Create an angle that is 5.625 degrees.
Construct a right angle.
Bisect the right angle 4 times. You will get an angle that is 5.625 degrees

Step 3: Construct an angle that is 72 degrees.
Create a Golden Triangle (two sides equal to phi and the base is 1).
One of the base angles will be 72 degrees.

Step 4: Join angles from Step 1 - 3 together (Euclid Book 1 proposition 23). You will get an angle that is 78.09 degrees. Make a an isosceles triangle with sides = 1. The base will be very close to the cubed root of 2.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!